# The \xnn Escape Sequence in C

Tags: c

I read that this escape sequence, **\xnn**, in **C** is used to represent single characters using hexadecimal character codes or values. Can I get a simple example program of this escape sequence, for I'm not sure on how to implement it, for I'm not quite clear on its purpose.

Comment: It's used to represent single characters / bytes *in a string or `char` literal*.  Context is important.  As for an example program, it's unclear what one would write, as it is unclear what aspect(s) of these escape sequences are unclear to you.

Comment: `char* s = "abc";` is the same as `char* s = "\x61\x62\x63";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I get a simple example program of this escape sequence

```
char* s = "abc";
```

can also be coded as:

```
char* s = "\x61\x62\x63";
```

> I'm not quite clear on its purpose.

In addition to the usual characters that can be typed easily, 
the C11 standard identifies the following *simple-escape-sequence*s:

```
\' \" \? \\
\a \b \f \n \r \t \v
```

If a character cannot be typed easily and it cannot be represented by using one of the simple escape sequences, you will have to resort the using `\xnn` (hexadecimal escape sequence) or `\nnn` (octal escape sequence).

Comment: This clarifies its usage/purpose for me perfectly : ) Thanks, R Sahu.