# How to print a parenthesis in C with printf?

Tags: c, printing, compiler-errors, printf, printf-debugging

I am trying to print a parenthesis using:
printf("\)");
However, it is giving me the following warning:
warning: unknown escape sequence '\)'

I can't seem to find a clear explanation anywhere on how to fix this. 
I realize it's just a warning, but since it's still treating that as a parenthesis it's throwing off all my other parentheses and giving me errors so that the code does not compile.

EDIT: Treating it as a regular character and just saying printf(")") is not working. It's still mismatching all the parentheses and I have gone through multiple times to make sure I'm not actually missing any.

Comment: Parentheses are not special characters in C string or character literals, they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Drop the escape sequence. Use just `")"`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34958449/434551 for valid escape sequences.

Comment: I was treating it as a regular character and it was still throwing off all of my parenthesis, that's why I tried escaping it.

Comment: I'm not getting any warnings/errors on my computer... (http://rextester.com/MTOR1328)

Comment: Nevermind, I'm stupid and was recursively calling a function by the wrong name, which gave me errors related to parenthesis so I assumed it had to be the print statement.

Comment: Happens to the best of us... Anyways cheers for figuring it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is coming from the C compiler. It is telling you that `\` is not a known escape sequence in C. You need to double-escape the slash, like so: `\\`

**Edit:** if you just want to print the parenthesis, i.e. the `)` then drop the slash altogether and use:

```
printf(")");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Printing quotation mark \")\" ");
}
```

you need to add an escape character to get the quote to print which in this case is \"

This will result in Printing quotation mark ")"

Answer (score 0):

just write parenthesis in double quote " " ,because parenthesis is not a escape character .

try this :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
 printf( "(  )" ); // print  parenthesis here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

Using variables seems to be a viable solution using my compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char var = ')';
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("Success :%c",var); //As you can see this is one way to go about the problem
    return 0;
}
```